# Выполнится ли Cron поставленный на 31 число, в месяце из 28/29/30 дней?

Tags: linux, cron

Поставил:

```
Min 59
Hour 23
Day 31
Month *
Day of week *
```

Но как известно, в месяце бывает 28, 29, 30 и 31 день.
Выполнится ли крон 30 сентября? 31го в нем нет.

Comment: Если в кроне ничего существенно не поменялось в последнее время (о чем я не знаю), то не выполнится без специальных обвесов. Тут идея такая: если не принципиально, то выполняете скрипт в первую минуту первого дня каждого месяца. Если же принципиально, то выполняете скрипт 28-31 го числа каждого месяца, предварительно в скрипте делая вычисления - является ли текущая дата последним днем текущего месяца.

Comment: @de_frag опубликуете как ответ?

Comment: В `man 5 crontab` (по крайней мере, в дебиановской поставке) этому делу посвящён целый раздел «LIMITATIONS». Бонусом идёт удивительный пример с запуском в последнюю субботу месяца, но ширина полей не позволяет привести его здесь :)

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, `cron` (а точнее выражения `crontab`) не имеет параметров, задающих последний день текущего месяца.

Чтобы запустить свой скрипт в последнюю минуту последнего дня текущего месяца, придется запускать 4 дня подряд с 28-го по 31-е в 23:59, предварительно вычисляя в скрипте - является ли текущая дата последним днем текущего месяца:

```
59 23 28-31 * * /path/to/myscript.sh
```

Скрипт myscript.sh должен содержать в начале код, вычисляющий условие "последнего дня месяца".

Интернеты предлагают [различные обвесы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month) по вычислению требуемого условия прямо в `crontab`.

Например, такое:

```
55 23 28-31 * * echo "[ $(date -d +1day +%d) -eq 1 ] && my.sh" | /bin/bash
```

и даже вот такое:

```
55 23 L * * /full/path/to/command
```

но тут модификатор `L` нестандартный, и как говорит вики, относится к реализации cron-а  [Quartz_(scheduler)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(scheduler)).

По итогу надо выбирать решение, подходящее под ваше окружение: операционную систему, оболочку (которая может оказаться совсем не bash), язык программирования, etc.

В дополнение.

Новомодные таймеры `systemd` с определенной версии (пишут, что с 233-й) вроде как получили возможность запускаться в последний день месяца, используя знак `"~"`. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v233/NEWS#L174

> Calendar time specifications in .timer units now support
>             specifications relative to the end of a month by using "~" instead of
>             "-" as separator between month and day. For example, "*-02~03" means
>             "the third last day in February". In addition a new syntax for
>             repeated events has been added using the "/" character. For example,
>             "9..17/2:00" means "every two hours from 9am to 5pm".

Comment: man 5 crontab говорит `Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input` отсюда `+\%d ` нужно указывать во втором примере

Comment: @PotroNik в данном примере знак "%" в этой команде не в чистом виде - он находится внутри команды `test` <- внутри двойных кавычек <- внутри команды `echo`, поэтому скорее всего это делать не надо. Но лучше проверить, да.